# Лікар та доктор - це синоніми?

Tags: вживання-слів, вибір-слова

Чи є різниця між словами "лікар" та "доктор". У СУМі вказується, що "доктор" - це "те саме, що лікар". Однак, згідно до сайту [Моя освіта](http://moyaosvita.com.ua/medicina/chim-doktor-vidriznyayetsya-vid-likarya/) різниця між цими словами існує, адже: "**Лікар** – це практикуючий фахівець з медичною освітою, який має відповідну кваліфікацію за фахом. **Доктор** – це наступна за кандидатом наук вчений ступінь, яка характеризує людину, як дослідника. Доктор наук (навіть по медицині) не обов’язково повинен бути лікарем. Лікар, у свою чергу, зовсім не зобов’язаний мати вчений ступінь доктора або кандидата".

Крім того, якщо це все ж таки різні слова, то чому у перекладі назви серії оповідань ["Шерлок Холмс і доктор Ватсон"](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A8%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%A5%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BC%D1%81_%D1%96_%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BD) Ватсона називають "доктором", адже згідно до Вікіпедії він був лікарем ("Ватсон — британський лікар, співмешканець, асистент та просто друг видатного Шерлока Холмса"). Така ж сама справа із назвою відомого телесеріалу "[Доктор Хаус](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D0%A5%D0%B0%D1%83%D1%81)", де Хаус також працює лікарем-діагностом, а не дослідником.

Отож, виходить, що ми все ж таки можемо вживати ці слова як синоніми?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У [Словнику синонімів Л. Полюги](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=23&t=2093) знаходимо:

> **лікар**
>
> (той, що лікує хворих) медик, **доктор**, жарт, ескулап, (що лікує нетрадиційними методами, часто зі словом народний,) цілитель.

У [Словнику синонімів Караванського](http://slovopedia.org.ua/41/53403/267213.html):

> **ЛІКАР**
>
> **доктор**, ж. ескулап, зн. коновал; (народній) знахур; (внутрішніх хвороб) терапевт, (дитячий) педіятр; (костоправ) хірург; (зубний) дентист; (тварин) ветеринар; (визнавець гомеопатії) гомеопат; (рядовий, у лікарні) ординатор; лікарчук.

Також знаходимо в [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80):

> **ЛІ́КАР** (особа з вищою медичною освітою, що лікує хворих), МЕ́ДИК, **ДО́КТОР** розм.,ЕСКУЛА́П жарт. заст.,ЛІЧЕ́ЦЬзаст.; ЦІЛИ́ТЕЛЬ книжн. уроч., ЗЦІЛИ́ТЕЛЬ книжн. уроч. (той, хто зціляє, виліковує); КОНОВА́Л зневажл. (поганий лікар).

При пошуку синонімів до слова **доктор** знаходимо:

> **ДОКТОР**
>
> **лікар**, ж. ескулап, ір. цілитель; **(науковий ступінь) доктор наук.**

За інформацією з цих словників **лікар** і **доктор** вживаються як синоніми (враховуючи навіть *науковий ступінь*). Хоча, зрозуміло, що інформація подана на сайті [Моя освіта](http://moyaosvita.com.ua/medicina/chim-doktor-vidriznyayetsya-vid-likarya/) логічно обгрунтована. Однак, думаю, що слово **доктор** на позначення **лікар** вживається досі в нашій мові із колишнім значенням, яке в словнику з позначкою *розм.* і не має значення наукового ступеня.